# C# sqldataadapter datatablemapping

Tags: c#, datatable, sqldataadapter, columnmappings

I have a query - "`SELECT PK1 FROM users`";

I also have a datatable named `myTable` with three fields of type int;

```
-----------
| myTable |
-----------
| field1  |
| field2  |
| field3  |
-----------
```

For each row returned from my query, I would like to put the PK1 value into field2 in `myTable` leaving field1 and field3 null.

Here's some sample code I have tried so far, but it doesn't seem to be working. Instead, the field PK1 is appended to the end of `myTable` as a new field.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string SQL = "SELECT PK1 FROM users";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection([my connection string]);
            DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection);
            myTable.Columns.Add("field1", typeof(Int32));
            myTable.Columns.Add("field2", typeof(Int32));
            myTable.Columns.Add("field3", typeof(Int32));
            DataTableMapping dataMapping = adapter.TableMappings.Add("myTable", "users");
            dataMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("PK1", "field2");

            adapter.Fill(myTable);

            foreach (DataRow row in myTable.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("------------");
                foreach (DataColumn column in myTable.Columns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName + " : " + row[column]);
                }
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Is there an issue in my code, or is there another way I can map the fields across?

This is a simplified example for the purposes of this question, as such mapping the field names would be ideal rather than inserting the value at a given position.

Comment: It's 2012, why are you using `DataTable`?

Comment: Because I would like to be able to store the data in memory and manipulate it further before persisting to a second DB. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: I should also add that this is my first C# project so any tips / alternatives are more than welcome as this will be a learning experience for me.

Comment: You could create a class that better represents the data you're manipulating and use some type of ORM ([NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/)) to persist the changes.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would create the class and the objects?

Comment: Also, would it be possible for you to explain why this approach is superior to using DataTable / why I shouldn't be using DataTable?

Comment: For a brief list of pros/cons for the DataTable see [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2007/04/04/datatable-vs-bindinglist-t.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if it is your requirement then there is nothing wrong with this approach. 
Change your query to the following, and you don't need the mapping.

```
string SQL = "SELECT PK1 as field2 FROM users";
```

Comment: Hi Asif, thanks - however the problem is that I would like to insert the value of PK1 into field2. However my code leaves all three fields null and adds a new field of PK1 to the end of my DataTable

Comment: Thanks Asif - using this as a workaround will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is adding the column because you are telling it to. You should either use the datamappingColumn feature or the table.column.add feature not both, they are redundant, and probably not necessary.

So if you leave the table.column.add()

Here is an example of how you would "bind" the column names to the columns you set in table, you specify the order in which you want them to appear, you can leave them blank by "" double quote or set them to null by using NULL.

this.table.AutoSetDataBoundColumnHeaders = true;
this.table.SetDataBinding(table, null, "PK1", null);

Comment: The DataTable doesn't seem to have either of these methods?